# How to identify the BLANK terminal on remote SSH?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, terminal, jsch

I am executing some commands on the remote `ssh` connected through `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell`

Assume, I am executing the command "A" and press `Enter`. After 10 sec the `terminal` should prompt screen to enter the next command say "B".

In my case, if prompting for command "B" is delayed more than 10 sec. I need to `log` as TIMED OUT.

Post execution of `cmd` A. terminal displays a blank screen with the cursor at top left corner.

Any way to identify the blank screen through `ChannelShell`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you implementing?

Comment: Hi, A requirement from client. Hence, I am supposed to incorporate it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using 'timeout' to implement the 10 seconds timeout on command "A". This will require executing the following, instead of the current `command-A`

```
    timeout 10s command-A ; [ $(kill -l $?) = ALRM ] && echo "TIMED OUT"
```